# What kinds of line segments/edges require high accuracy in a true surface-of-the-ellipsoid representation?

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, representation, ellipsoid, geodesic

I've been musing (and doing prototype coding) for a 'projection free' geographic codebase with your basic point, line & polygon primitives.

Rather than dealing with all the sacrifices that come along with projecting to the plane, however, I'm writing algorithms that work directly on the surface of the ellipsoid.

One of the potential complications is that there are different kinds of "lines" out there:

- (arcs of) great circles: shortest distance along the (constant-zero-elevation) surface between two points; should correspond exactly to line-of-sight paths.
- rhumb lines: connect the two points with a path of constant direction -- for example, some state borders follow lines of latitude (which are not great circles).
- curves: circular arcs (paths of constant distance from a given center-point); Bezier (not sure on correct re-interpretation in the context of a curved surface), etc.

Of the different kinds of paths (including ones I missed), which are important enough that they have an 'exact' representation, vs representing within an error bounds by short segments of a simpler path (e.g. short geodesic arc segments)?

Clarification edits: by 'exact' above, I mean parametric. In other words: computable to any desired accuracy, without a a densification-on-import step.

**An edit**, much later, to add a citation I've come across that closely parallels my own thoughts on the use of 3D unit vectors as a geographic primitive: [A Non-singular Horizontal Position Representation](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=7787653) ([alt link](http://www.navlab.net/Publications/A_Nonsingular_Horizontal_Position_Representation.pdf)). Best part? I didn't have to write it all out myself!

Comment: Truly *exact* representations of any of these objects on any ellipsoid (which is not a sphere) is next to impossible.  The geodesics are no longer portions of great circles in general; the rhumb lines will be nasty no matter what; geodesic circular arcs will be particularly messy.  Is there really any point to doing this that is worth a couple of orders of magnitude of additional computation for every operation?

Comment: Nothing is exact with that interpretation of the word -- how about "parametric" instead as a better word choice?  (Also, as a side note: if I restrict myself to spheroids rather than general ellipsoids, the parametric representations are somewhat less messy.)

However, it's true that a lot of those things remain extremely messy/difficult --- hence my question! I'm not interested in a system which destroys existing data quality, but I don't feel a need to represent curves nobody is using either.

Comment: I've worked with great circle line segments on a spheroid represented as a pole of rotation (point at lat/long) with a start angle, and end angle.  I found it difficult to visualize the math used to manipulate them (quaternions). http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B8H31-4NWMMJ8-15&_user=10&_coverDate=12/31/1996&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1630644141&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=64253404dcc4146066d5f7128855488c&searchtype=a

Comment: @Kirk: An easier-to-work-with representation (opinion here!) is to use orthographic 3D coordinates and represent the start/end points as vectors -- you're still using quaternions (to represent rotations in 3D) but they're much easier to think about.

Comment: @Dan - but with 3d coords, you'd need to densify in order to maintain constant elevation, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Kirk: I'm not saying to use straight 3D lines, just a 3D orthographic coordinate system. ;) For example, a great circle on the sphere is the intersection of a plane with the surface of the sphere. Want to find where two great circles cross? Intersect their planes. (Want to walk a point along a great circle arc? [Slerp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) from the start vector to the end vector). All in all, it's easier (for me) to conceptualise, and avoids a lot of trig for many operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question concerns what kinds of curves deserve an implicitly exact representation rather than a discretized approximation.  The crux of the matter is this: to be successful, the class of curves you support in this manner must be closed under the class of curve- and polygon-creation operations supported in the GIS.

These operations include:

- **Buffering.** In this process, you need to construct curves that are parallel to features.  ("Parallel" means in the sense of maintaining a fixed distance.)  This includes *circles* and portions thereof (for buffering points), *oblique parallels* (which are curves equidistant to geodesics on the spheroid, and can reduce to isolated points in special cases), and *concentric circles.*  On the sphere (but not, generally, on an ellipsoid) the oblique parallels are themselves circles.
- **Polygons of influence** (Thiessen polygons; Voronoi polygons; Dirichlet cells).  To construct the Thiessen polygons for a collection of point features we need to find bisecting lines, which are geodesics (they are straight); but for a collection of other kinds of features, such as points and segments, the boundaries of the Thiessen polygons include portions of parabolas (in the plane).  Maybe you don't want to support this...
- **Set-theoretic overlays** (intersection, union, difference, complement).  These operations do not create any new kinds of curves.
- **Parallel translation and rotation**.  These are usually not possible to perform exactly on an ellipsoid (because it is not a [homogeneous space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space)), but are straightforward on the sphere.  On the sphere, these operations do not create new kinds of curves.

The really problematic class of curves you propose consists of the general rhumb lines (loxodromes). Lines of latitude are rhumb lines but (on the sphere at least) they are also circles, so they present no additional problem.  But general rhumb lines are complicated beasts: if they are not meridians or parallels, they spiral into one pole or the other.  Buffers and parallel translations of rhumb lines will be genuinely new types of curves.  You would have to represent these results as broken segments of lines and circles, which would defeat your purpose (and be fairly difficult to compute).  Therefore I suggest *not* trying to support rhumb lines exactly.

In sum, it looks like you can be successful in your program if (a) you work on a spherical model of the earth rather than the more general ellipsoidal ("spheroidal") model and (b) you limit certain constructions such as Thiessen polygons (and medial axes, which are closely related) to collections of points.

Comment: I really like this way of thinking about it. A few random thoughts in following comments...

Comment: Nit: Buffering is fixed-distance, not parallel (except for infinite lines).

Comment: On the plane, areas of influence for straight-sided features have straight-line and conic-section curves in their borders -- but I doubt that it is closed. I've actually no idea what curves form the boundary of influence for (conic-section) curved features themselves; maybe some deep thought/research will reveal that they're conic sections too, but I'm skeptical. Being closed in general under these operation seems very unlikely.

Comment: Set-theoretic operations: Planar GIS systems typically aren't closed under set complement since it creates an infinitely-sized polygon; sphere/sphereoid/ellipsoid can do better. Note that sometimes intersection points can't (or a difficult) to represent for a lot of curve typess, though, even on the plane.

Comment: Translation/rotation: Affine transforms are possible on the plane, although there are other non-affine transform possible that might actually make *more* sense by making them specifically non-affine. E.g: "move every point due north by 150 meters" is often what is meant by a simple translation in a lot of projections, but of course the distortions of the projection mean that intent is slightly undermined...

Comment: Overall: There's a general approach to 'parametric' operations that may make sense, which is to store raw inputs, the operation, and (re)compute to a useful precision each time on-demand. ;) It's usefulness is limited though, and it's not a panacea -- you have to be very careful when e.g. deciding if things intersect...

Comment: An example of that general approach is found in a lot of 3D cad/ray-tracing -- instead of trying to compute the shape of the intersection/union/difference of two objects, they store both and have conditionals on the rays. (Eg, a ray-hit test for the intersection of objects A and B = if ray hits object A AND ray hits B.)

Comment: @Dan Quick responses: (i) An edit clarifies "parallel."  (Of course there are no parallel *geodesics* on a spheroid.) (ii) Voronoi regions for conics are not generally bounded by conics; no closure there. (iii) There's no problem with complements of polygons in the plane: handle those with the boundary orientation. (iv) Working on the sphere you want to use rotations, not affine maps; but on the ellipsoid there is no transitive group of isometries. (v) I agree about the limited usefulness of the just-in-time computing approach.

Comment: @whuber Would either one of these point in polygon methods work on a spheroid? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon If not, what method(s) would you propose?

Comment: @Kirk Suitably interpreted, they both work.  *Ray casting* determines whether two points lie within the same component of the sphere determined by a closed, non-self intersecting polyline.  The *winding number* is a basic tool of Complex Analysis, which naturally treats the sphere (with a single point removed) as the set of complex numbers by means of stereographic projection.  All geodesics on the sphere become circles or lines in the complex plane, so you get curvilinear polygons. That's no problem; for instance, use Mobius transformations to straighten circular arcs conformally.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the explanation. So since it is possible, what are the benefits?  Would this approach help resolve dateline issues?  If you move a polygon across a sphere so that it straddles the dateline, would there be any extra processing required (like inserting a vertex at the dateline crossing?)

Comment: @Kirk: As whuber said, they both work -- and should not require any special cases whatsoever for the dateline or the poles. This is a big part of my motivation for the approach: all operations work everywhere. To be overly dramatic, it would be nice to stop the (useful) lies we tell ourselves every time we perform a GIS analysis, namely that the Earth is flat. ;)

Comment: @Whuber You don't have to project everything to a plane for PiP methods. I was thinking of going the other direction, representing edges as three-dimensional objects that form the appropriate curve at their intersection with the surface of the earth, then doing a 3D ray-cast to infinity to count the even/odd or winding numbers. (Note that great circles on the sphere correspond to planes in 3D, meaning that you can test a geodesic polygon edge with a single ray-plane intersection and 3 plane-side tests. No trig!)

Comment: @Dan Projection is a matter of how you think about things.  After all, the use of (lat, lon) to parameterize the sphere is a projection everywhere except at the poles.  Trig is inevitable in converting from those coordinates to 3D.  A disadvantage with the 3D solution is that the dimensions all go up by one, essentially guaranteeing everything you do will be more complex.  After a stereographic projection you can solve the PiP problem without trig, either.

Comment: @whuber: Let me concisely make the case for geocentric 3d unit vectors as a primary representation. Consider two points, a & b, represented so. Then we have: geodesic_dist(a,b) = radius*acos(dot(a,b)). great_circle(a,b) = cross(a,b). (As the normal vect of the corresponding plane). closest_point(a, great_circle(b,c)) = (solve for plane at right angle to the (b,c) plane through a; intersect planes). construct_point(start_point, initial_bearing, dist) is 3D rotation. geodesic_edge(a,b) can be represented by great_circle(a,b) plane and two planes perpendicular to it, one each through a and b.

Comment: @whuber Comment limits prevented me from clarifying that I was talking about points/geodesics/etc on the sphere. (Some of it carries over to a wgs84-style spheroid, though, via the auxiliary sphere.)

Comment: @whuber: This is a placeholder comment to make your mailbox light up --- you may be interested in the citation I edited into the main question!

Comment: @Dan I found it online at http://www.navlab.net/Publications/A_Nonsingular_Horizontal_Position_Representation.pdf .  I guess I found it uninteresting for the simple reason that it explains the usual way that one goes about doing any calculations on the sphere or ellipsoid: you convert (lat, lon) to the Cartesian coordinates of a normal vector and then do analytic geometry or calculus in three dimensions.  This is the way to work with DEMs, too.  This method is usually lesson 1 in any differential geometry textbook; e.g., see Chapter 2.2 of http://www.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf

Comment: @whuber: Check the alt link? "N-vector" is a weird shortening of "normal vector" and you will be disappointed if you expect new mathematics there at all. It is, however, a decent exposition & accompanying advocacy of 3D unit vectors as a geographic primitive of choice for representing a point on the surface of the earth.

Comment: @whuber --- I don't think you'll find much on numerical stability or ease of implementation in Chapter 1. However, that was more or less the whole point of the paper, and those topics aren't very interesting from a pure maths point of view at all. Sorry to disappoint! A question for you: If Step One in doing any interesting calculations is converting to a vector, then why on earth (hah) isn't it a good idea to use vectors as a primary representation in the first place, and relegate lat/lon to a mere data-exchange representation?

Comment: @Dan (1) OK, quickly now: approximately where on the world are (0.208, -0.725, 0.656) and (-0.389, -0.732, 0.559)?  About how many time zones apart are they?  What's the bearing between them?  What is the climate like in those two places?  Having *simple*, *meaningful* coordinates to locate places on the earth is useful.  (2) Why use three numbers for data exchange when two work just fine?  (3) To project the ellipsoid (that is, *make a map*), sometimes normal vectors will be good, but most of the time they would have to be converted back to (lat, lon) anyway.  That's inefficient.

Comment: RE: (1) Yes, they aren't as intuitive. (2) I think lat/lon are a great data exchange representation & said so. RE: (3), I'm skeptical. The vast majority of projections have an awful lot of trig that smells significantly like the exact opposite of what you're saying -- that is, they begin their first step by converting lat/lon to a cartesian space. E.g. a mercator's y component is a nonlinearly scaled version of a vector's "north" (z/y depending on convention) coordinate...

Comment: @Dan Only a few of the simpler projections have that property, Dan, and only for the sphere as far as I can tell.  Leaf through the formulas in Snyder's *Map Projections--A Working Manual* to see what I mean.  On balance there is much in favor of a normal-vector representation of locations, but before plunging in to an implementation it's good to research the possible negative effects.

Answer (score 4):

Dan,

You may be interested in some of the work I've been doing on geodesics.
This is described in this [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1215).
In particular, note:

- The direct and inverse geodesics problems may be solved to machine
  precision.  This means about 15 nm for double precision.  I can switch
  to long doubles, add an extra term in the series, and get accuracy of
  6 pm.  Note in particular, that the solution to the inverse problem
  always converges (unlike Vincenty's method).  The speed is comparable
  to Vincenty's method (direct solution is somewhat faster, the inverse
  solution is somewhat slower).
- I compute the reduced length and geodesic scales.  These quantities
  give the differential properties of geodesics, and allow various
  geodesic problems (intersections, median lines, etc.) to be solved
  quickly and accurately using Newton's method.  The curvature of the
  boundaries of buffer regions can be expressed in terms of these
  quantities.  See this
  [note](http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2011-July/005775.html)
  that I sent to the proj.4 mailing list.
- I define an ellipsoidal gnomonic projection in which geodesics are
  very nearly straight.  This allows problems on the surface of the
  ellipsoid to be mapped to problems in plane geometry.  For example,
  the intersection of two geodesics can be found exactly by estimating
  an intersection point, performing a gnomonic projection about that
  point, re-estimating the intersection and iterating.
- I give expressions for the area of a geodesic polygon.  There's no
  need to subdivide long edges to get an accurate result.
- GeographicLib (on sourceforge) implements the algorithms.
- Finally, I remark that for many purposes geodesics are preferable to
  any other sort of curve (in particular great ellipses or rhumb lines)
  because they obey the triangle inequality.  This has several
  consequences:

  - Geodesics and geodesic circles intersect at right angles.
  - The shortest XXX line between a point P and an arbitrary curve C
    intersects C at right angles only if XXX = geodesic.
  - Geodesics are a natural way to partition data using a quadtree
    because bounds can be place on the range of distances between a
    arbitrary point and all the points within a quadnode.

Comment: Thank you for sharing these ideas; it's a *very* nice paper containing some great work.  Welcome to our site!  Some remarks and questions follow.  (1) In what sense do "geodesics and geodesic circles intersect at right angles"?  You must have some restriction in mind because this is not generally true.  (2) The 3D Euclidean distances @Dan refers to will also satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: (1) Consider all the geodesics emanating from a point A; this defines
one family of curves.  Consider next all the geodesic circles centered
at A; this defines a second family of curves.  Because of the triangle
inequality, these two families are orthogonal.  This gives one of the
basic properties of the azimuthal equidistant projection.

(2) Yes you're right, of course.  If you're thoroughly into the world of
the geometry of surfaces, you recoil at the idea of any properties which
depend on how the surface is embedded in 3d space.  (See Gauss'
"Remarkable Theorem".)

Comment: Actually (1) is more general: in any Riemannian manifold, a geodesic from a point *P* outside a smooth curve *c* to a point on *c* that minimizes the distance between *P* and *c* must be orthogonal to *c*.  Your statement about "geodesic circles" immediately follows (provided *P* is the center: that's the previously unstated restriction).  I agree with the sentiment expressed after (2), but we must remember that the objective here is to perform accurate efficient calculations, rather than investigate intrinsic properties of the surface.  A well-chosen embedding might facilitate that.

Comment: A belated thanks for this reply. :) I'm too underwater to do more than skim at the moment, but it looks to be a a quite fantastic trove. A quick note on geodesic intersections since you called them out -- mostly for you to review as a check on my own undercaffinated intuition: Exact intersections of spherical geodesics can be found easily by intersecting the planes of the corresponding great circles, and that result carries over to ellipsoids by using an auxiliary sphere -- or am I missing something there?

Comment: @Dan

I composed an answer to your question.  But it seems that comments are
limits in length.  So see the next answer instead.

Comment: See also this paper: C. F. F. Karney, Algorithms for Geodesics, J. Geod, DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to @Dan's question about using the auxiliary sphere
to solve intersection problems.

No, the auxiliary sphere doesn't let you solve for intersections
directly.  The problem is that the mapping from the ellipsoid to the
sphere depends on the geodesic (e.g., its azimuth at the equator).  Thus
the auxiliary sphere is good for solving for a single geodesic but not
for solving any problem involving more that one geodesic.

My recommended way to do geodesic intersections and interceptions
(shortest path between a point and a geodesic) is to use the gnomonic
projection.  Geodesics on a sphere map to straight lines in the gnomonic
projection and so, provided that your problem is confined to a
hemisphere, the gnomonic projection converts these problems to 2d ones.

There is no projection which preserves the straightness of geodesics for
an ellipsoid (because its curvature is not constant).  However,
GeographicLib provides a generalization of the gnomonic projection in
which geodesics are very nearly straight.  This leads to rapidly
converging algorithms for geodesic intersection and interceptions (again
provided that the points are all well within a hemisphere).  See my
answers (with code!) to gpesquero at

https://sourceforge.net/projects/geographiclib/forums/forum/1026621/topic/4085561

Finally, I'd like to point out that I've recently converted
GeographicLib's geodesic routines to Javascript, so that you can play
around with them in Google Maps.  See

http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/scripts/geod-google.html

http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/scripts/geod-calc.html

(I didn't convert the gnomonic projection to Javascript yet.  That would
be reasonably straight forward.  I would also convert the azimuthal
equidistant projection at the same time, since that's a convenient way
to solve another class of geodesic problems involving "median lines".)

**ADDENDUM (2014-08-19)**

It's also possible to solve for the time of closest approach for two vessels traveling at constant speed along geodesics.  Because we know the differential properties of geodesics, it's possible to use Newton's method to get an accurate solution in a few iterations.  Code to implement this is posted at

https://sourceforge.net/p/geographiclib/discussion/1026620/thread/33ce09e0

Comment: I'm quite sure I'm off track, but not sure where; I'd love it if you could help debug my reasoning. (Next comment.) Otherwise: thanks a heap for the helpful code + commentary + link; it's tremendously useful.

Comment: Here goes, as concisely as I could make it. My reasoning is expressed in 3D Cartesian, not angular coords: (a) On a sphere, all points in a great circle are coplanar. (b) The transformation to the auxiliary sphere is linear and invertible. (Mistaken thinking?) (c) All points in an elliptical geodesic transform to points along a great circle on the aux. sphere. (d) All points on an elliptical geodesic are coplanar as well, due to (b). Finally, (e): Due to coplanarity, two candidate geodesic intersection points on the ellipsoid can be found by plane intersection.

Comment: @Dan, An ellipsoidal geodesic does not lie in a plane.  (If it did, it
would have to be a plane curve; and yet we know that, in general, on
each circuit of the globe the geodesic falls short by an amount O(f).)
The fault in your reasoning is (b) -- the connection between the
aux. sphere and the ellipsoid is not linear.  The latitude
transformation is equivalent to a stretch in the z direction and so is
linear.  However the longitudes are related by a elliptic integral and
this prevents there being any simple linear relationship.